# good tool for remote debugging the android devices in different geographic location

Tags: android, mobile

Since I have just started learning android and very new to android environment also.

My question is I have few android devices which is connected to remote windows machine ( which is in different geographic location ) and for debugging purpose is there any android tool **(like VNC)** so that i can take control of devices connected to remote machine.

My main aim is to take control of android devices (mobile devices) like switch ON or OFF Wi-Fi or install/uninstall app connected to the remote system.

Thanks

Comment: What device do you need? http://www.ironlab.io allows debugging on real devices in the cloud. They are in free beta now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSTF developed **STF** which is an open source platforme to manage debug device. It's well tested for device farm and offer **remote log**, **remote control** (touch, wifi, lock and so on)

[Everything you need to know is here](https://github.com/openstf/stf/).

Official website [here](https://openstf.io/).